# how to use mutate to create variable applying function by rows

Tags: r, apply, dplyr

I have a data frame and I want to create a new variable applying a function that works within rows. See the example below.

```
library(tidyverse)

n <- 100
z0 <- data.frame(A = sample(c("y","n",NA), n, replace = T, prob = c(.4,.4,.1)),
                 B = sample(c("y","n",NA), n, replace = T, prob = c(.4,.4,.1)),
                 C = sample(c("y","n",NA), n, replace = T, prob = c(.4,.4,.1)))

z0 %>% apply(1, function(x) any("y" == x)) -> z0$new
summary(z0)
```

I would want to do it with mutate but I have fail. I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Do you want `new` to equal `TRUE` if any columns A:C == `y`?

Comment: that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach. Let's create a data frame with all the possibilities to make sure nothing gets missed.

```
library(tidyverse)
(z0 <- data_frame(A = c("y", "n", NA, NA, NA), 
                 B = c("n", "n", "y", "n", NA), 
                 C = c("n", "n", "n", "n", NA)))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   A     B     C    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 y     n     n    
#> 2 n     n     n    
#> 3 <NA>  y     n    
#> 4 <NA>  n     n    
#> 5 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```

Here's a safe approach using `purrr::pmap_lgl` that requires you to explicitly put in which variables you want to include to see where `"y"` might appear:

```
z0 %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap_lgl(., ~ any("y" == c(..1, ..2, ..3))))
```

Here's an approach using `purrrlyr` (a small package with some functions orphaned from `purrr`) which has the benefit of using `...` to indicate all variables:

```
z0 %>% 
  purrrlyr::by_row(~ any("y" == ...), .collate = "rows", .to = "new")
```

Both give the same result:

```
#> # tibble [5 × 4]
#>   A     B     C     new
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <lgl>  
#> 1 y     n     n     TRUE   
#> 2 n     n     n     FALSE  
#> 3 <NA>  y     n     TRUE   
#> 4 <NA>  n     n     NA     
#> 5 <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  NA
```

EDIT: The first solution (so-called "safe") doesn't work with factor variables (and possibly other classes) [as discussed here](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358#issuecomment-363091446). Seems like things get coerced to numeric, which is why this (very silly) code gives the desired result:

```
z0 %>% 
  mutate(new = pmap(., 
     ~ any(as.numeric(factor("y", levels = c("n", "y"))) == 
           c(..1, ..2, ..3))))
```

Comment: behavior of `%in%` is different of `==`, I tried to replace `%in%` for `==` but error came out.

Comment: The only difference I can think of is that `any("y" == x)` returns `NA` when `x` is all `NA` while `y %in% x` returns `FALSE` in that case. Which do you want?

Comment: I NEED `==` behavior. see for example `any("y" == c("n","n",NA))` and `any("y" %in% c("n","n",NA))`.

Comment: OK - always best to include the desired output in the original question.

Comment: the desired output is the same as `z0 %>% apply(1, function(x) any("y" == x))`. sorry if it wasn't clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ngm. Would you pointout some reource to learn the double dot usage as in `mutate(new = pmap_lgl(., ~ any("y" == c(..1, ..2, ..3))))`? is new for me. Thanks.

Comment: I must point out that your solution works if the data frame is created using `data_frame()` and doesn't works if the data frame is created with `data.frame()`.

Comment: Indeed - and related to a possible `R` bug discussed here and elsewhere: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/358#issuecomment-363091446

Comment: Also, be aware that when you use `data.frame` any character vectors are coerced to `factor` variables. This is almost always undesirable, which is why the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` option to `data.frame` is almost always the right thing to do. Or at least be aware that you are creating factors.

Answer (score 2):

This will work with factors or character columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
z0 %>% 
  mutate(new_var = rowSums(.[c('A','B','C')] == 'y', na.rm = T) > 0)
```

Another option (slower I'd guess) is to use `rowwise`

```
z0 %>% 
  mutate_at(c('A', 'B', 'C'), as.character) %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(newvar = any(c(A, B, C) == 'y', na.rm = T))
```

Comment: Should have `na.rm = TRUE` in there too.

Comment: Unless OP wants `NA` to be returned when the whole row is `NA` in which case this approach doesn't work at all.

Comment: Agree with ngm. That isn't what I want

Comment: @NicolasMolano Edited

Comment: @Renu I must point out that the solution which uses `rowSums` isn't good. In the second, It works but taking `na.rm =F`. It should be noted the use of `transpose` in your solution, this highlights the difficulty of using functions based on rows to create variables with mutate.

Comment: I think the issue is that OP wants the answer to a row with no `"y"` and one or more `NA` to be `NA` (what I finally acheived in my answer) and not `FALSE` (which is what you get and what I originally had).